# Java 8: How to pass Map<K, V> and List<K, V> subtypes as parameters

Tags: java

I am working on a Java EE project, in which I need a structure to keep `key-List<value>` in RAM. I created a class which looks like this:

```
public class ListMap<K, V> {
    private Map<K, List<V>> map;
    private Class<? extends List<V>> listClass;

    public ListMap(Class<? extends Map<K, List<V>>> mapClass, Class<? extends List<V>> listClass) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        this.map = mapClass.newInstance();
        this.listClass = listClass;
    }

    public void add(K key, V val) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        if (map.containsKey(key))
            map.get(key).add(val);
        else {
            List<V> valList = listClass.newInstance();
            valList.add(val);

            map.put(key, valList);
        }
    }

    public Map<K, List<V>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public <T extends Map<K, List<V>>> T getMap(Class<T> cls) {
        return cls.cast(map);
    }

    public void setMap(Map<K, List<V>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

I tried doing it like this:

```
ListMap<String, String> msgs = new ListMap<>(HashMap.class, ArrayList.class);
```

But, its not working. Can anyone please tell me how can I instantiate this class?

Comment: Are you using Java 8? Also, define "_not working_" - post the full compile error or stacktrace.

Comment: You don't need to pass `mapClass`: just pass an already-built `Map`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, yup

Comment: Then just pass a `Supplier`. Why use reflection?

Comment: A `Supplier<? extends List<V>>`, that is. (And a `Supplier<? extends Map<K, List<V>>`, if you don't want to pass in an already-build `Map`).

Comment: Unless you're implementing this just for fun, take a look at [Guava's Multimaps](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained).

Comment: @BoristheSpider, compile-time error is as follows: `argument mismatch; java.lang.Class<java.util.HashMap> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends java.util.Map<K,java.util.List<V>>>`

Comment: Thanks @BoristheSpider, @andy-turner. I guess I have to settle for Java 8 `Supplier` for now.

Comment: @PrakharMishra define "settle for"?? Abstracting behaviour was the entire reason lambdas were rolled out in Java 8.

Comment: The question is in which context this is going to be used i.e. what purpose this ListMap is going to serve and at how many places. Using Java 8 perhaps `map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value)` is already everything that you need.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, no matter what solution you throw at me, a compilable class should always be instantiable (if not marked as `abstract`, of course). It should have worked the way I wanted it to... Seems to me like a flaw in language design.

Comment: @PrakharMishra sorry but false. For a simple example, a utility `class` should not be. For a more interesting example, is an `enum` instantiable? In the more general case, it is trivial to create a method that can never be called by playing with generic co/contra-variance; the same is true of a constructor.

Comment: To me this looks like one more [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). @Prakhar, what do you really trying to achieve? Can you describe your problem that you need such a `ListMap` class for? Then we might be able to come up with a suitable solution.

Comment: @SergGr, like I said, I want an in-memory structure to store `key-List<value>`. At first, I was using a list of objects. Then, there came a need in which I had to apply a `groupby` on certain attribute of value in the list. So, I thought it will be a good idea to keep a *groupedby* list, instead of a flat list to begin with (performance friendly).

Comment: @Prakhar, this doesn't answer a question why you need customization of `mapClass` and `listClass`. What's wrong with using standard `HashMap` and `ArrayList` every time?

Comment: @serggr, because I had one more requirement of having a TreeMap instead of HashMap, which keeps the keys in naturally sorted order. Just wanted to make ListMap generic enough to handle that.

Comment: @PrakharMishra, you still don't say what you _real_ problem is. Why do you need `setMap` method? It would be very helpful, if you provide your actual usage scenarios rather than your halfway attempts to solve the real problem. Just one more example why we need it: what exactly is wrong with having your `add` as just a static method that accepts `Map<K, List<V>>` as the first argument and then you can pass any `Map` subclass there? Without usage requirements it is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the issues is that you can't put generics on the class declaration e.g. `HashMap<String, String>.class`

would this work for you?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ListMap<K, V> {
    private Map<K, List<V>> map;
    private Class<? extends List<V>> listClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ListMap(Map<K, List<V>> map, List<V> listType) {
        this.map = map;
        this.listClass = (Class<? extends List<V>>) listType.getClass();
    }

    public void add(K key, V val) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        if (map.containsKey(key))
            map.get(key).add(val);
        else {
            List<V> valList = listClass.newInstance();
            valList.add(val);

            map.put(key, valList);
        }
    }

    public Map<K, List<V>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public <T extends Map<K, List<V>>> T getMap(Class<T> cls) {
        return cls.cast(map);
    }

    public void setMap(Map<K, List<V>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        new ListMap<>(new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>(), new ArrayList<String>());
    }
}
```